# Define train/test set and use in function based on if-statement

Tags: python, pandas, function

I want to test different models based on values in a dataframe, and use the same train and test sets in the whole process. However, when splitting the variables I cannot use them in the function. This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx') # Load in dataset

X = df.iloc[:,2:] # features
y = df.iloc[:,0] # Metastases (1) or not (0)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)  # Define StratifiedKFold with 5 splits

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index], X.loc[test_index] 
    y_train, y_test = y.loc[train_index], y.loc[test_index] 

def model(variable):
    if model == 'clinical':
        X_train=pd.DataFrame(X_train.iloc[:,:6])
        X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test.iloc[:, :6])
    return (X_train, X_test)
    if model == 'radiomic' or model == 'combined':
        X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train))
        X_test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_test))
    return (X_train, X_test)

clinical_train, clinical_test = model('clinical')
```

I would expect when calling the function to get different dataframe according to the if-statement. I get the error: UnboundLocalError: local variable `'X_train'` referenced before assignment.

I have tried the following already:

1. Make `X_train` etc global variables before splitting
2. Do the splitting within the function, but this gives me different train and test sets each time I call the function
3. Place the function in the for loop

Comment: I think `return` statements in your `model` function should be inside `if` statements.

Comment: You should not call `model` a function that returns train/tests datasets. Why not call it `get_train_test_samples` or similar.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan this gives me the following error: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `return` is outside your if statement, therefore it will still return variable even if it doesn't fulfill the if statement.

However, you may transfer if statement to if-elif-else statement:

```
def model(variable):
    if model == 'clinical':
        X_train=pd.DataFrame(X_train.iloc[:,:6])
        X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test.iloc[:, :6])
    elif model == 'radiomic' or model == 'combined':
        X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train))
        X_test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_test))
    else:
        # You may raise error
        X_train = None
        X_test = None
    return (X_train, X_test)
```

Besides, it is appreciated if you could provide a few rows of sample so that we could follow.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same error. If I make `X_train` etc a global variable, it does not change anything based on the if-statement.

Comment: How do you call the function `model`? I cannot see it is executed in your code

Comment: As `clinical_train, clinical_test = model('clinical')` for example.